# How to filter string in C# using linq to exclude all letters and numbers?

Tags: c#, string, linq

I need to filter a given string to a string in which all letters and numbers are excluded using LINQ in C#?

Comment: Please show an example of input and output. + what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the regex solution, but in linq:

```
var s = new string("abc123!$%^".Where(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var filtered = new string(
    "Monkey!123"
        .Where(x => !char.IsDigit(x))
        .Where(x => !char.IsLetter(x))
        .ToArray());
```

It gives `"!"` in my example.

Comment: Any reason behind the two `Where`s instead of `&&`?

Comment: @RandRandom - Yes, two reasons. (1) Clarity - I think `&&` makes conditions more difficult to read. (2) Composability - if I want to copy and paste an individual where-clause I can if they are separate.

Comment: @RandRandom - Yes, it will slow it down by two millionth of a nano second for every 100 years of operation. Just joking. It's negligible.

Comment: :D :D :D :D :D :D